# How to split strings using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, string

I created a form in HTML that accepts one input value. This input is a series of numbers and letters which I need to split up in order to extract information from. I started writing out my code in JavaScript, and I realized that it is tough to manipulate strings, so I am trying to code it in PHP now.

What I want to do is when I receive this string, I want to be able to cut it out, and output it into a table in HTML, which I would eventually export into a database in SQL. How would I go about doing this, and is it possible to do this without causing the user to go to another page in the website (like how JavaScript runs functions on click of the submit button).

EDIT: I'm sorry if I was unclear, so Ill give it another go.
For example, say you have a string 1Z3043EDG3513426. I want to extract only two parts from it, the part that comes after the "G", and the part between "Z" and "E". Once I get these two values, I want to output it into a table, which I want to keep updating each time a new string is added. That is what I need help with doing.

The ultimate goal for me is to take these values which I extracted from the string and store it into a database.

Hope that helped a bit

Comment: try *something* when you get stuck post your code

Comment: but... *processing* strings is easier in JS than in PHP :(

Comment: Post at least the input string and desired split algorithm in pseudo.

Comment: Hey you are using SO, but need help writing coherent titles and questions

Comment: If you want to split your strings into an array, and your split-points are non-trivial, consider using regular expressions with [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). As @candle says, you can use AJAX to do the background processing feature, but don't worry about that until you've written the actual function.

Comment: Please do not reverse good edits unless they change the meaning of your question. I felt the original title was too chatty, so I made it more succinct, and the same for the bit about whether the question was clear (people will not be shy about letting you know on Stack Overflow). There were some clear-cut instances of case errors I fixed too. I have therefore rolled back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to cut the string's some last or first characters, you can use `substr()` function, i.e. `substr(string, starting_point, ending point)`. First character would be start at 0, if you want to remove last 2 characters use -2 as the third parameter. Example:

```
<?php
$str= substr("abcdef", 0, -1);  // returns "abcde"
$str= substr("abcdef", 2, -1);  // returns "cde"
$str= substr("abcdef", 4, -4);  // returns false
$str= substr("abcdef", -3, -1); // returns "de"
?>
```

If you want to break down your string by certain character (for example "," , ":" , "." etc.) you can use `explode()` function. Just give delimiter as a first parameter, and a string as a second. And you will get an array with already broken down strings. Example:

```
<?
$sentence = "I.love.php";
$words    = explode(".", $sentence);
echo $words[0]; // returns "I"
echo $words[1]; // returns "love"
echo $words[2]; // returns "php"
?>
```

And if you don't want cause users move to another page you should use AJAX. But if you are new to AJAX, I think you can easier use PHP code to make the "stay on the same page effect". This is not so good practice (I don't recommend this)but if you want:
In PHP file (that one with the form), in the `<form>` tag write the name of that PHP file (here "form.php" is used). This will give the sense to user that they stayed on the same page:

```
<form   action="form.php" method="POST">
<input  type="text"       name="title">
<button type="submit">    Submit</button>
</form>

<?
if(isset($_POST["title"]))
{
  //do what you want with data you got
  echo $_POST["title"]."<br>";
}
?>
```